# How to have searborn dist and box plot on the same graph one above the other with a single x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I want to make two plots with seaborn of the same distribution one above the other and with only one x axis: the one of the bottom figure.

This piece of code almost achieves this, but:
 1. The ranges on the two x-axes are not the same
 2. I want the top x axis not to appear.

```
import seaborn as sns    
f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
x = range(1,100)
sns.distplot(x,ax=axes[0])
sns.boxplot(x,ax=axes[1])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved both my problems.